# Looking for education materials about App Maker

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker, rad

Last year Google launched a RAD platform, that is called [App Maker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/).

It looks promising for my needs, as it's quite often when I need to build something small in a short time.

Surprisingly, but there are no many educational materials. All I could find so far is just official documentation, while I would like to learn how to build a real production app with some course.

Is there, maybe, some free video course about App Maker?

Comment: Your question is off topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App Maker Academy is a free educational video course about App maker that covers the following topics:
 - Introduction to App Maker
 - View Fragments
 - Database
 - Scripts and Integrations
 - Debugging and App Maker Settings
 - Styling and CSS

http://appmakeracademy.com (via learn.by)

P.S. During the whole course, starting from the basics of the App Maker platform and to the advanced Platform techniques, you will continue to work on the real production application.